# Why does vim solarized colorscheme looks weird on my mac?

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I installed [solarized colorscheme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized) and configure things in vimrc

However, on my mac, it looks like:

[image: vim on mac]

After I added a line `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` in vimrc, it looks a little better:

[image]

But it's still not the color on solarized, on a linux machine(without `let g:solarized_termcolors=256` in vimrc), it's like this:

[image]

So how can I make the colors on mac vim the same as on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't work for me either, I didn't spend too much time on researching why it wouldn't work, and turn to this one: https://github.com/lifepillar/vim-solarized8

And it works for me, try if it's working for you :)

BTW, be aware it does fall back to an approximate palette based theme if your terminal is not supporting true colors, I'm using windows terminal and it works fine, you actually don't have to put "set termguicolors" in your .vimrc. Hope it helps

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The reason seems to be that my terminal isn't supporting true colors.